# align facet plot with another plot (without facet)

Tags: r, ggplot2, vertical-alignment, facet-wrap

Good evening,

I am trying to verticaly align a multi facets plot with a plot without facet. Indeed, the first plot is using continous values in x (time serie) and the facetting discriminate the group conditions. The second plot is using these group conditions as discrete x values.

Please see the example below :
[Example of the 2 plots non aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPxzJ.png)

This plot is generated using grid.arrange()

```
grid.arrange(plotGrowth, plotqPCR, ncol=1)
```

So to align them I tried different solutions:

```
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(plot1), ggplotGrob(plot2), size = "last"))
```

or

```
library(gtable)
library(grid) # low-level grid functions are required
g1 <- ggplotGrob(plot1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(plot2)
g <- rbind(g1, g2, size="first") # stack the two plots
```

But basically I am always getting the same error:
**Error: ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE**, which suggest that R does not manage as the first plot is made of 15 columns and the thecond one by 1....

I imagine that one solution would be to make R considering the first 15 facets plot as 1 plot of 1 column, however I have no idea of how to do so. There are however probably better ways to do it, so please if you have any idea, I will greatly appreciate.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tested your solution and the one from Tung, and both are working perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Try [**`cowplot`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/)

```
    cowplot::plot_grid(plotGrowth, plotqPCR, 
                       ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, 1),
                       align = 'v', axis = 'lr')
```

or [**`patchwork`**](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) for `ggplot2`

```
    plotGrowth + plotqPCR + plot_layout(nrow = 2, heights = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: Dear Tung, Thanks a lot ! your cowplot is working perfectly fine